# Will I get in trouble if I miscapitalize on the works cited page?

Tags: citations

I just realized after submitted my works cited page that I used uppercase letters instead of lower case. For example Federalizing Medical Campaigns against Alcoholism and Drug Abuse. Instead I capitalized it all. Is that something I would get in trouble for?

Comment: Where did you submit it?

Comment: Miscapitalize on? As in, make money out of? Oh, you mean capital letters. Look, noone will care. Really. Worse problems happen with references all the time. Here is a famous one: "Death of Dr. O. Uplavici", http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1659886/pdf/calwestmed00357-0034a.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: Thank you for your confession. The Interpol Typography Squad (SHOUTY DIVISION) will be visiting you shortly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to worry.

People have a hard enough time agreeing about what should be capitalized at all.  No people who is concerned with the *content* of your work will care in the least about capitalization that is consistent and at least vaguely plausible.  Many people will not even notice.

Rather, what you should expect is:

- If there are review stages and you will have a chance to revise, it will make no difference to the decision you receive, and you can fix it in the next revision.
- If there is no further review/revision stage pending, then:

  - If the venue you submitted it will send it through a proof-reader before publication (e.g., some journals), then it will get corrected to their preferred standards in the final proofing before publication.
  - Otherwise, you can expect to see the errors in print, entirely unremarked upon.

Comment: For some reason I get the feeling that the OP is referring to coursework, in which case the instructor might actually care about capitalization.

Comment: @ff524 If that's so, then I would expect to close the question as "undergraduate only" --- I've answered as I think would be expected for anything at graduate level and beyond.

Comment: I consider this question "unclear what you're asking," hopefully the OP will come back and address Nate Eldredge's comment.